# How do I tell the alert package to use growl on windows 7?

Tags: microsoft-windows, notifications

I would like to use the `alert.el` package for notifications on windows 7. Therefore, I installed growl for windows and I can trigger notifications by using `growlnotify.exe`.

When customizing the alert package, there is an entry:

```
 Alert Growl Command: c:/Program Files/Tools/growlnotify.exe
```

But when I evaluate `(alert "This is an alert")`, nothing happens... I see no way to say alert to actually *use* growl. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the Growl code in `alert.el` is incomplete.

If you redefine `alert-growl-notify` following this pull request at [Github](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert/pull/34/files) , then Growl should work for you.